# Xcode iOS 10 and 9 constraint problems

Tags: xcode, ipad, constraints, ios9, ios10

I've got two iPads one with iOS 10 and the other with iOS 9. The UI builds fine on the iOS 10 but the 9 version, the constraints seem to be going crazy. (The text inside a button is being chopped/ only half of the text is showing)

But on the iPhone with version 9 & 10 the UI works fine?

I'm just seeing if anyone else is having the same problem? or know what's going on?

All the best !

Answer (score 1):

Try to uncheck the Relative to Margin option for each and every constraint. Tap on the UI control -> Go to the Size Inspector -> Double click constraint and check the margin, just turn it off and fix your constraint if anything changes.